# PHP preventing direct access to a php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

links.php which has following codes:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
<p><a href="track.php?page=http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">google.co.uk</a></p>
<p><a href="track.php?page=http://www.bbc.co.uk" target="_blank">bbc.co.uk</a></p>
<p><a href="track.php?page=http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a></p>
<p><a href="track.php?page=http://www.yahoo.co.uk" target="_blank">yahoo.co.uk</a></p>
```

track.php which captures the link clicked:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb1") or die(mysql_error());

$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$page_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO link_track (myurl, myip1, mydate) VALUES ('$redirect', '$ipaddress', now())") or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: $redirect");
```

Is there anyway to prevent someone from directly accessing the track.php.

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you.

---

my apology for additional question:
If I want to strip out `http://www.` part from the url can I modify my track.php code as followings:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb1") or die(mysql_error());

$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
$redirect2 = parse_url($redirect, PHP_URL_HOST);
$redirect2 = preg_replace('/^(www\.)/i', '', $redirect2);
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$page_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO link_track (myurl, myip1, mydate) VALUES ('$redirect2', '$ipaddress', now())") or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: $redirect");
```

Comment: No. There's a way for everything. You can obfuscate it. But you can't block it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408538/what-checks-to-use-to-prevent-direct-access-to-pages-using-php?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044643/php-prevent-direct-access-to-page

Comment: is your track.php loaded in any kind of template ie: if you load it correctly it has a header or something included if its loaded directly that header etc isn't included ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stop someone from directly accessing it as it would need to be web accessible for your links to work, but you could handle exceptions where the URL query string doesn't contain the page parameter.

Example

```
if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
   header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
   exit('400: Bad Request');
} else {
   // code from current track.php

}
```

Comment: my apology for additional question:

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the user with the help of `session`

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = 1;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location:links.php");
    }else {
// your insert query
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous as the user session may be compromise by other user