# Prevent php direct page access in the url bar

Tags: php, session-variables, sessionid

I am doing a small application in core php.Here my database for login is something like this

```
id
firstname
lastname
email
userid
account_type
contactno
password
```

in login file the code is something like this

```
<?php
    include_once("include/connection.php");
    session_start();
    session_unset();
?>
<?php
      $msg="";
    if(isset($_REQUEST['sub'])){
        $pswd=sha1($_REQUEST['psd']);
        $sel=mysql_query("select * from login where userid='".$_REQUEST['uid']."' and password='".$pswd."'");

        $rowsel=mysql_num_rows($sel);
        if($rowsel==1){
            $selacc=mysql_fetch_array($sel);
            if($selacc['status']!='banned'){
              $_SESSION['uid']=$selacc['userid'];
              $_SESSION['uname']=$selacc['fname']." ".$selacc['lname'];
              $_SESSION['upassword']=$selacc['password'];
              $_SESSION['acctype']=$selacc['acctype'];
              $_SESSION['agentcode']=$selacc['agent_code'];
              $_SESSION['authentication']="authenticated";
          header("location:dashboard.php");
          }
        }
        else{
          $msg="Enter Valid Username Password";
        }
    }
?>
<body>
    <form name="login-form" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="uid" class="inputbox" />
    <input type="password" name="psd" class="inputbox" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="" class="inputbotton" />
  </form>
```

Now after the login the user is directed is `dashboard`. But from here when I am typing directly ``one page name(lets say posts.php) it is redirected to the post.php file. But here I want one denied access that when someone will direct enter the page name in the url(like post.php) it should show some error. But when the page is normal redirect then it should show the page.I want to prevent the direct page access in the address bar but when the page is normal redirected it should show the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preventing direct access to a php page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344747/php-preventing-direct-access-to-a-php-page)

Comment: Rather than worrying about whether somebody typed into the address bar (which is pretty much impossible to detect *reliably*), why not just check the session at the beginning of each page to see if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Just check the any session variable set in previous page for example

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     echo 'error';
     exit;
 }
```

do it on the top

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 factors in it.

1) your folders and files permissions on server.

2) When you login first time, it should show you login page. But when you do the same thing again. The variable stores in session until you close your browser. So, Close the browser and try again. You need to check if session id is set or not, and make decision according to that.